# Usar funciones de un servicio en otro servicio con Nestjs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, nestjs

Tengo un módulo en el cual se recibe un archivo `XLSX`. Al ser enviado por el cliente se guarda en el servidor. Posterior a guardarse se obtiene el contenido en un array de objetos.

Estoy tratando, con la información obtenida, de registrar estos datos en una base de datos.

Ejemplo:

Los datos obtenidos:

```
[
 {'name': 'Adams', 'age': 33, 'email': 'adams@test.ec'},
 {'name': 'Lila', 'age': 23, 'email': 'lila@test.ec'},
 {'name': 'Fred', 'age': 31, 'email': 'fred@test.ec'}
]
```

Lo que busco es que cada uno de esos objetos puedan ser usados para registrarse en la base de datos, añadiendo los campos de `id`, `created_at` y `updated_at`.

Para ello cuento con el módulo `Person`, con el servicio, el controlador, la entidad y el Dto, correspondiente.

Al tratar de usar la función para registrar una persona debo pasar por parametro el Dto:

**personService.ts**

```
//Person hace referencia a la Entidad ya inyectada en el servicio 
async createPerson(data: CreatePersonDto): Promise<Person>{
 try{
  return await this.personReposiory.save(data); 
 }catch(e){
  throw new Error(error.message)
 }
}
```

**createPerson-dto.ts**

```
export class CreatePersonDto {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({
    type:'timestamp',
    name:'created_at'
  })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    type:'timestamp',
    name:'updated_at'
  })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  name: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsNumber()
  age: number;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  emil: string;
}
```

Tomando en cuenta que la función `createPerson` esta siendo llamada desde otro servicio, que ya cuenta con la importación requerida. ¿Como hago para que mi objeto, obtenido del array, pueda ser valido como lo describe el Dto del módulo `Person`?

Comment: Puedes llamar la función`validate` de forma explícita  https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Esta utilizando class-transformer class-validator? comienza por allí, instalalo y has esto:

Importa las funciones necesarias en tu servicio:

```
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import { validate } from 'class-validator';
```

Ahora, cambia tu función createPerson para validar y transformar el objeto antes de guardarlo:

```
async createPerson(data: any): Promise<Person> {
  const personDto = plainToClass(CreatePersonDto, data);
  
  const errors = await validate(personDto);

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    throw new Error(`Validation failed: ${errors.map(error => Object.values(error.constraints).join(', ')).join(', ')}`);
  }

  try {
    return await this.personReposiory.save(personDto);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
}
```